# JQuery show after hiding (this)

Tags: jquery, show-hide

The element I need to show is the ".triggerso" element, (which was hidden to show the ".panelso" panel). When the user clicks the ".panelso" element I'd like the ".triggerso" element to return.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".triggerso").click(function(){
    $(this).hide();
    $(".panelso").show("fast");
    $(".panel").hide("slow");
    $(".panel1").hide("slow");
    $(".panel2").hide("slow");
    $(".panel3").hide("slow");
    return false;
```

Check out the ["Social"](http://www.blairdog.com/testsite/bdpanel.html) tab at the top of the page.
I'm new to JQuery and have searched and searched, any help would be appreciated!

Thanks so much,
Andrea

Comment: It seems you have found a solution with the help of the community. Please accept an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure if i entirely understand, but you could just add,

```
$('.panelso').click(function(){
$('.triggerso').show();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$(".panelso").click(function() {
 $(".triggerso").show();
}
```

This should work, unless you have multiple items with class .triggerso on your page?

Comment: $(document).ready(function(){
 $(".triggerso").click(function(){
  $(this).hide();
  $(".panelso").show("fast");
  $('.panelso').click(function(){ 
  $(this).hide();
  $('.triggerso').show("fast"); });
  $(".panel").hide("slow");
  $(".panel1").hide("slow");
  $(".panel2").hide("slow");
  $(".panel3").hide("slow");
  return false;
});
});

Answer (score 2):

try this...

```
$(".panelso").click(function() {
 $(".triggerso").show();
}
```